# How to check a checkbox and date in a formula?

Tags: formula

I am quite new to formula.
I want to check tow conditions in a formula.
I have a checkbox x and date y.
Like if(x is unchecked and y+90) then do some action.
How to use formula for the above condition.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's possible that a formula might not be the right answer here.

Comment: All a formula can do is calculate data, to do an action you need something like a workflow.  What does "y+90" mean?

Comment: I want to check a condition in process builder if  a checkbox x is not checked and the initial date entered =today - 90(3months) then do some action.

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce you really need to complete the Trailhead tutorial modules like [Formulas and Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/point_click_business_logic) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax should work in a workflow condition and you may need to adapt it for process builder since process builder formulas do not accept the same syntax as workflow formula conditions

```
IF(AND(NOT(X__c),(DATEVALUE(Y__c) + 90) == TODAY()),true,false)
```

Perhaps you could use a formula like that in your condition.  The condition will be true when both `X__c` is unchecked and `Y__c` is 90 days before today.